# How do I get site usage from IIS?

Tags: asp.net, iis

I want to build a list of User-Url
How can I do that ?

Comment: just to clarify - you want to analyse IIS metabase and generate a list of all pages?

Comment: no, to have statistics about users entrance to my site pages.
For example:
Michael - www.mysite.com/books.aspx + Date + Time
Tom - www.mysite.com/HomePage.aspx + Date + Time

and so on..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, IIS creates log files in the system32\LogFiles directory of your Windows folder. Each website has its own folder beginning in “W3SVC” then incrementing sequentially from there (i.e. “W3SVC1”, “W3SVC2” etc). In there you’ll find a series of log files containing details of each request to your website.

To analyse the files, you can either parse them manually (i.e. suck them into SQL Server and query them) or use a tool like [WebTrends Log Analyser](http://www.versiontracker.com/dyn/moreinfo/win/7922). Having said that, if you really want to track website usage you might be better off taking a look at [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics). Much simpler to use without dealing with large volumes of log files or paying heft license fees.

Comment: I think IIS v. 6.2 (2012) puts the log file directories (W3SVCx) in `<inetpubBaseDirectory>\logs\LogFiles`, (i.e. usually `C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles`)

Answer (score 0):

if you have any means of identifying your users via web server logs (e.g. username in the cookie) then you can do it by parsing your web logs and getting info from csUriquery and csCookie fields.

Alternatively you can rely on external tracking systems (e.g Omniture)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding the log files in `C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles`.

I used [Log Parser Studio](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/exchange-team-blog/introducing-log-parser-studio/ba-p/601131) from Microsoft to parse the data. It has lots of documentation on how to query iis log files, including sample querys.